# Log in to Meteor with Twitter, Delete tweets as user

Tags: meteor, twitter

My users are logging into my Meteor App using twitter, and I receive their token and secret. The app's purpose is to help the user delete old tweets, and so I want to be able to delete tweets on the user's timeline. Do I use my app's consumer and secret or do I need the user's? Do I need to somehow authorize my application to delete the user's tweets?

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like more of a twitter API question.have you consolted the docs for their API yet on how to delete a tweet?

Comment: I've read them to the best of my ability. It simply says that you need auth, and then gives the endpoint to hit.